# Integration of $\int \frac{1}{1+\tan^{2023}(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need to find this integration
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+\tan^{2023}(x)}dx.$$
**My Attempt**

I tried to find the integration by using
$$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx.$$
The technique above can be used when I do
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\tan{x})dx.$$

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @grand_chat Thankyou. Your link works for me.